# Contour integral with finite limits

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration, complex-integration

I have the following integral
$$I=\int_a^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2-\frac{1}{x^2}},$$
where $a>0$.
This integral contains a pole at $x=1$, and I rewrite the integral as
$$\int_a^\infty \frac{x^2}{x^4-1}dx=\int_a^\infty \frac{x^2}{(x+1)(x^2+1)(x-1)}dx.$$

I'm not sure how deforming the contour works in this case with finite limits. My attempt was to break up the integral as
$$I=\text{lim}_{\epsilon\to0}\left(\int_a^{1-\epsilon} \frac{x^2}{x^4-1}dx+\int_{1+\epsilon}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{x^4-1}dx\right),$$
analytically extend the function to a complex function $f(x)\to f(z),\,z\in\mathbb{C}$, and then take a contour that goes as follows
$$I_C=I+I_R+I_{\epsilon},$$
where $I_R$ is a big arc extending in the complex z plane connecting $a$ and $\infty$, $I_\epsilon$ is a small arc connecting $1-\epsilon$ and $1+\epsilon$, and $I$ is composed of the straight line segments from $a$ to $1-\epsilon$ and $1+\epsilon$ to $\infty$.

If the contour encircles the pole, we will have that
$$I_C=2\pi i\,\text{Res}\bigg[\frac{z^2}{z^4-1}\bigg]=\frac{i\pi}{2}.$$
If I parametrise the $\epsilon$ arc by $z-1=re^{i\theta}$, the small arc integral is

$$I_\epsilon=\frac{i\pi}{4}.$$

Parametrising the big arc as $z=Re^{i\phi}$, the integral scales like $\frac{1}{R}$ and so the integral over the big arc vanishes. I'm not certain about this step since we have finite limits.

Therefore I'm left with
$$\frac{i\pi}{2}=I+0+\frac{i\pi}{4}\rightarrow\,I=\frac{i\pi}{4}.$$

However this isn't the answer given in my source, there they say that for $a<1$ one gets
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\left(\text{tanh}^{-1}a+\frac{\pi}{2}-\text{tan}^{-1}a-\frac{i\pi}{4}\right).$$

I don't understand how they reach this answer.

**Update:**
If I calculate the principal value of the integral, I find
$$\text{lim}_{\epsilon\to0}\left(\int_a^{1-\epsilon} \frac{x^2}{x^4-1}dx+\int_{1+\epsilon}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{x^4-1}dx\right)=\frac{1}{4}\left(-2\text{tan}^{-1}a+2\text{tanh}^{-1}a+\pi\right),$$

which is almost the answer, it's just missing the $\frac{-i\pi}{4}$, so what am I missing in this calculation?

Comment: The integral isn't defined because, as you noted, the integrand has a first-order pole. You'd first have to define what you mean by that integral. What you're calculating is the [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value). Since we don't know your source, it's impossible to tell whether that's what the source means by this integral.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure what you mean. All I've been given is the integral on the first line, and told to integrate it for a<1. I also know that I can analytically continue x to a complex variable z. That's all I have been given

Comment: Then what you've been given makes no sense. That integral isn't defined. You can't integrate over a pole. You can say what you mean by integrating over a pole (with the usual options being infinitesimally avoiding the pole clockwise, infinitesimally avoiding the pole counterclockwise, or taking the principal value, which amounts to the average of the other two), but if you don't, then it's undefined.

Comment: I thought that's what I was doing by defining the contour integral? I am avoiding the pole by going around it via the complex plane with a small arc. Most of the contour integral questions I have seen on here just give the integral as I did in the first line and say they want to perform the contour integral.

Comment: As far as I can tell, what you're doing is defining the undefined integral using the principal value (your $I=\text{lim}_{\epsilon\to0}\ldots$ equation) and then calculating that principal value using a contour that avoids the pole to obtain a closed contour – but then you subtract that part out to obtain the principal value. Then you complain that your result doesn't match the source. Since you don't know whether the source intended the undefined integral to be interpreted as the principal value as you did, there was no reason to expect that your result would match the result in the source.

Comment: As regards other contour integral questions on this site: I've been around the site for a while, and I've answered quite a few contour integral questions, and I don't remember even once seeing a question that assumed that an integral over a pole was well-defined without specifying how it's to be interpreted. If you've seen such questions, please link to them.

Comment: I didnr understand the big arc and  the integral on it.

Comment: All I know is that the source gives the answer for the undefined integral as $$I=\frac{1}{2}\left(\text{tan}^{-1}a+\frac{\pi}{2}-\text{tan}^{-1}-\frac{i\pi}{4}\right),$$ and I am trying to understand how they could reach that. As I described in my previous comment I think it's clear that I am trying to define it via contour integration, and if there's any mistake in what I have done, or if there is a better way to do this, I would like to know.  That is what I am asking for help with.

Comment: And for example in this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1079750/integral-with-contour-integration-int-infty0-frac2x2-1x41-dx they simply state they are trying to evaluate the integral via contour integration, I don't see what is so different to my question where I also say I want to do it via contour integration and I describe the contours.

Comment: @furious.neutrino in the question you linked, the poles are not being integrated over.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3805052/cauchy-principal-value-of-int-infty-infty-fraceipxx4-1-mathrm here is an example similar to mine. I think it is clear now from my comments and edits what I am trying to do, but I have not yet obtained an answer to my question.

Comment: "The integral over the big arc vanishes". No, it does not. You have handled the big arc haphazardly without carefully examining what you are doing. If the integral had been from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, you would be correct. but it is not. It is from $a$ to $\infty$, and integration near the end of that arc at $z=a$ does not scale with $1/R$. I suggest adding a separate integral from $0$ to $a$, which you will need to do the old-fashioned way, and then exploiting a certain property of your integrand to get an integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Concerning your small arc. which of the two arcs about $z=1$ are you taking? Did you account for the direction of travel along that arc? Did you account for the fact that you are only going halfway around that circle, not the whole way? Concerning joriki's point. The integral you are doing is actually undefined. By approaching the singularity evenly from both sides at the same time, you are doing the "Cauchy Principle Value" integral, not the Riemann (or even the Lesbegue) integral.

Comment: Hello, yes I accounted for the fact that you only go half way around, and since I was making the contour such that the pole at $z=1$ is encircled, I went anti-clockwise around it, so from $\pi$ to $2\pi$. I realise now that the issue is with the big arc, I assumed it goes to zero but now I don't think it does. I was able to solve the problem using the Sokhotski–Plemelj theorem, but I would still like to understand how to do this entirely through the Cauchy principal value integral.